# Set selected date for TimePicker(Extended Toolkit - WPF) control

Tags: c#, wpf, timepicker

In my WPF application, I want to set selected date for TimePicker control. In my application, I'm using calendar in one of my View window. When I select a date from calendar and change TimePicker value(i.e Time) and save then my entry saved to Today's date only. I want to save my entry to selected date. so, How to set select date for TimePicker control in this situation?

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
   <TextBox Name="CltText" Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
   <TextBox Name="AppText" Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
   <xctk:TimePicker Name="StartPicker" Value="{Binding StartValue, ElementName=MainWin, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
   <xctk:TimePicker Name="EndPicker" Value="{Binding EndValue, ElementName=MainWin, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="60" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
   <TextBox Name="TaskText" Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71"/>
   <ComboBox x:Name="ProjectComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=projectList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name"  SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="130" Background="Yellow" BorderThickness="0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution.

StartTimeText and StopTimeText are names of my Timepickers. Below lines will set Date as well as Time for these TimePickers.

```
StartTimeText.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month,DateTime.Now.Day,DateTime.Now.Hour,DateTime.Now.Minute,DateTime.Now.Second);
StopTimeText.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TimePicker returns a nullable DateTime object, so if you already have a DateTime object containing Date information, and you want to combine it with your second DateTime object containing Time information, you can do a DateTime.Parse, outputting them both as strings:

```
//date is your existing Date object, time is the nullable DateTime object from your TimePicker
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", date.Date.ToShortDateString(), time.Value.ToLongtTimeString()));
```